# How can I use a trigger to update a different table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

I have two MySQL tables. A votes table `(id, userId, postId, voteTypeId)`, and a posts table `(id, postTypeId, userId, parentId)` table. I'm writing a trigger that fires after insert on votes.

I would like the trigger to update a post in the posts table. But this post is not the same one referenced in my votes table under `postId`; It is the parent of that post.

```
BEGIN
CASE NEW.voteTypeId
    WHEN 2 THEN UPDATE posts SET posts.acceptedAnswerId = NEW.postId WHERE posts.id = @the parent postId of NEW.postId
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        END;
    END CASE;
END
```

I tried using this instead of @the parent of... :

```
(SELECT posts.parentId FROM posts WHERE posts.id = NEW.postId)
```

But you I don't think you can do SELECTS in triggers unless you use some type of SELECT INTO syntax. My only reference to the parent post that I want to update is its child postId in referenced in votes. So I don't know how to do the update without grabbing the right id through a select.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can in fact do a SELECT within a trigger. Your other syntax however looks a bit off.

Comment: @Mchl, I tried a few combinations, but it didn't work. Can you point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like that:

```
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.voteTypeId = 2) THEN
    UPDATE
      posts AS p
    CROSS JOIN
      posts AS p2
    ON
      p.id = p2.parentId
    SET
     p.acceptedAnswerId = NEW.postId
    WHERE
     p2.id = NEW.postId;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: thanks for that. Can I just ask you why you use a cross join? Why not just a normal join with an alias?

Comment: In MySQL `INNER JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN` and `JOIN` are all equivalent. Actually, according to ANSI SQL specification, I should have used `INNER JOIN` here (because I used `ON` join condition instead of `USING()`). Functionally it makes no difference, but potentially omproves portability.